# Three.js: Fresnel Shader - Lights: true issue

Tags: canvas, three.js, webgl, fragment-shader, fresnel

I have a small issue with the three.js example [fresnel shader](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_shaders_fresnel.html).

'lights : true' - if this is 'true' then I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
```

I'm clueless. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `ShaderMaterial.lights = true`, the renderer will populate the shader lights uniform parameters for you.

But you have to ensure that your shader has the necessary lights uniforms in the first place.

`THREE.FresnelShader` does not use lights as written; it relies on an environment map instead. Consequently, setting `lights: true` will have no effect.

But if you want to do it, and are willing to modify the shader, you have to replace

```
var shader = THREE.FresnelShader;
var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( shader.uniforms );
```

with

```
var shader = THREE.FresnelShader;

var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.merge( [

    THREE.UniformsLib[ "lights" ],
    shader.uniforms

] );
```

three.js r.59

Comment: Can I send you a beer? :) Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: I wish, but my reputation apparently is not high enough...all those hours playing GTA2...useless.

Tell me one thing, do you think is it's also possible to add a diffuse color to the shader material? I know that the it uses env map for the color, but maybe there is a blending method to achieve that? Or a fresnel material...

Comment: If you have further issues, you need to make a new post. This is for the benefit of others... Yes, anything can be done. Study the three.js examples. It's a steep learning curve. I'd suggest you first hardwire a color. Later, pass the color in.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046248/three-js-fresnel-shader-color-changing-or-env-map-blending

I've posted it here. I don't catch the part about passing the color in to the shader :/ I'm not the shaders pro...Thanks for any help