# Three.js: Fresnel Shader - Color changing or env map blending

Tags: canvas, three.js, webgl, fresnel

I'm not a shader specialist, but I'd like to pass the color value to the shader that could maybe blended with the env map color.

```
    var shader = THREE.FresnelShader;
// Thank you WestLangley for that trick
    var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.merge( [

        THREE.UniformsLib[ "lights" ],
        shader.uniforms

    ] );

    uniforms[ "tCube" ].value = textureCube;

    var parameters = { fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader, vertexShader: shader.vertexShader, uniforms: uniforms, lights : true };
    shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( parameters );
    shaderMaterial.envMap = textureCube;
```

I'm clueless. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

For the futures ones ;) You need to modify the FresnelShader firstly by passing the color to the shader. Afterwords in the fragmentShader add a line:

```
vec4 color = vec4( colorR, colorG, colorB, 1); // colorR,G,B those are floats passed to the shader
```

and by modifing this line:

```
gl_FragColor = mix( color, reflectedColor, clamp( vReflectionFactor, 0.0, 1.0 ) );
```

You can addjust the refracted color.